# What is the difference between 'ptr = &array[index]' and '*ptr = array[index]'?

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and having a hard time differentiating this syntax

```
ptr = &array[index]
```

against this one

```
*ptr = array[index]
```

---

In a sample function I worth

```
void getDevice(Device* device)
```

the line works just like I expect it to

```
*device = devices[index];
```

(de-referenced device pointer now has value `devices[index]`)

but this line causes segfault

```
device = &devices[index];
```

(device pointer has `devices[index]`'s address)

I think both ultimately should have same effect (`ptr` pointing to `devices[index]`). What am I missing here?

---

Actual code:

```
void populatePhysicalDevice(VkInstance* gInstance, VkPhysicalDevice* gPhysicalDevice)
{

  uint32_t physicalDeviceCount = 0;

  vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(*gInstance, &physicalDeviceCount, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

  VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevices[physicalDeviceCount];

  vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(*gInstance, &physicalDeviceCount, physicalDevices);

  int bestSuitedPhysicalDeviceLocation = 0;

  gPhysicalDevice  = &physicalDevices[bestSuitedPhysicalDeviceLocation]; // Causes segfault

  *gPhysicalDevice = physicalDevices[bestSuitedPhysicalDeviceLocation]; // Works
}
```

[`VkInstance`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkInstance.html)

[`VkPhysicalDevice`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDevice.html)

[`vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices.html)

Comment: What compiler are you using ? Did you try ` gPhysicalDevice  = &(physicalDevices[bestSuitedPhysicalDeviceLocation]);` Just to check for priority of your operators. When you say there is a segfault does it really ocuur at the line you are refferring or outside the function call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you call your function like so:

```
vkInstance instance;
vkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice;

vkCreateInstance(..., &instance);
populatePhysicalDevice(&instance, &physicalDevice);
```

So the two values of the two arguments passed are the pointers to `instance` and `physicalDevice` in the caller's scope. The pointers (not the values they point to) get *copied* into the corresponding variables in `populatePhysicalDevice`:

```
void populatePhysicalDevice(VkInstance* gInstance, VkPhysicalDevice* gPhysicalDevice)
{
```

So at this point, inside `populatePhysicalDevice()`, you have two pointers that you can change at will, but will not change anything in the caller's scope. Let's go on:

```
  uint32_t physicalDeviceCount = 0;
  vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(*gInstance, &physicalDeviceCount, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
  VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevices[physicalDeviceCount];
  vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(*gInstance, &physicalDeviceCount, physicalDevices);
```

Now you have a local array of `VKPhysicalDevice`s, that has been filled in by `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices()`. Now you want to ensure that the caller gets a copy of the best suited physical device:

```
  int bestSuitedPhysicalDeviceLocation = 0;

  gPhysicalDevice  = &physicalDevices[bestSuitedPhysicalDeviceLocation]; // Causes segfault
```

That line doesn't do anything that the caller will see. It will just change the local variabel `gPhysicalDevice` to point to the start of the local array `physicalDevices`. When you return, all those things go away. The end result is that `[hysicalDevice` in the caller's scope has not been initialized. That is the likely cause of the segmentation fault.

When you do this instead:

```
  *gPhysicalDevice = physicalDevices[bestSuitedPhysicalDeviceLocation]; // Works
```

You are actually copying the value of the first element of `physicalDevices[]` into the variable `physicalDevice` in the caller's scope.

Note that if you are just always going for the first physical device, you do not need to create a local array, you could instead just do:

```
void populatePhysicalDevice(VkInstance* gInstance, VkPhysicalDevice* gPhysicalDevice)
{
  vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(*gInstance, 1, gPhysicalDevices);
}
```

But don't forget that the instance might not actually have any physical devices available, so check the return values of the functions you call and make sure they are as expected!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Also would it be possible to 'copy' `&physicalDevices[index]` to `gPhysicalDevice` pointer? As in making this `gPhysicalDevice = &physicalDevices[index]` syntax somehow work.

Comment: You could make the function take a pointer to a pointer as a parameter, but then again, think about what you would make it point to. If you make it point into `physicalDevices`, which is an array allocated on the function's stack, it would point to undefined memory after the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr = &array[index]` sets `ptr` to point to `array[index]`. That is, it puts the address of `array[index]` into `ptr`.

`*ptr = array[index]` sets `*ptr` to the value `array[index]`. That is, it gets the value stored in `array[index]` and put that value in the place pointed to by `ptr`. It does not change `ptr`.

The cause of the segment fault you report cannot be ascertained because you have not provided sufficient code or information. The line `device = &devices[index];` by itself is likely not the cause.

Comment: Does that mean `*device`  and `devices[index]` will hold the same value for both of those approaches?

Comment: @atis: No, unless `index` is zero. `*device` is the first element that `device` points to, which is `device[0]`.

Comment: @atis: You should understand that `*ptr =` and `ptr =` are very different. The former sets a value in an array or other pointed-to object. The latter changes `ptr` to point to a different array or object.